# listview favorite icon gets Changed while scrolling listview

Tags: java, android, listview

i have a listView in which there is a textview for names and imageview for favorite button icon when i click on favorite icon icon changed to filled from unfilled but when i scroll the listview icon changed from filled to unfilled this is my code

```
    public class AdapterFind extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<BeanFindName> arrayListAd; /* arraylist with model class */
        Activity activity;
        DBFavourite dbfav;                   /* database class */

        private boolean[] favorites;           `ADDED`


        public AdapterFind(ArrayList<BeanFindName> arrayListAd, Activity           activity) {
            this.arrayListAd = arrayListAd;
            this.activity = activity;
            dbfav = new DBFavourite(activity);

            favorites = new boolean[this.arrayListAd.size()];    `ADDED`

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayListAd.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return arrayListAd.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {

            TextView txtID;
            TextView txtName;
            ImageView imvFavourite;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customized_listview, null);  /* layout file for listview row items */
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtID = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_tv_textId); /* textview id  */
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_lv_names); /* texview for names */
                holder.imvFavourite = (ImageView) convertView
                       .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_imv_favourite); /* imageview for favorite icons */

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtID.setText(String.valueOf(arrayListAd.get(position).getNameId())); /* model class functions */
            holder.txtName.setText(arrayListAd.get(position).getName());  /* model class functions */

            if (arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() > 0 || favorites[position]) {
                holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.customized_listview_iv_favourites_boy_filled);

            } else if (arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() == 0 || !favorites[position]) {
                holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.customized_listview_iv_favourites_boy_not_filled);
            }

            holder.imvFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

`ADDED`

      if (favorites[position] || arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() > 0) {  /* check for scrolling and database also to change favorite icon */
                        holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.customized_listview_iv_favourites_boy_not_filled);
                        dbfav.deleteByID(holder.txtID.getText().toString()); /* delete records from database*/
                        favorites[position] = false;
                    } else if (arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() == 0 || !favorites[position]) {                          holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.customized_listview_iv_favourites_boy_filled);
         dbfav.insertDataInFavourite(holder.txtID.getText().toString()); /*inserts records to database */
                        favorites[position] = true; 
                    }
                 }               
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is update the fav icon id in your data set which is your ArrayList upon onClick.

```
arrayListAd.get(position).setFinfavId(dark or light) 
notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

Comment: According to your code, you're trying to set the image icon to the view holder which will not work when the binding happens. Because your data set is not updated and still has the old values. By the way notifyDataSetInvalidated doesn't cause inefficiency as you think. It just refresh your views within the visible area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the information that a listview item is selected in the listview item itself so that when it is redrawn, it is redrawn with "selected" setting. To do so, let's add a field to `ViewHolder` class to store the same. I have added the code here:

```
public class AdapterFind extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<BeanFindName> arrayListAd; /* arraylist with model class */
Activity activity;
DBFavourite dbfav;                   /* database class */

public AdapterFind(ArrayList<BeanFindName> arrayListAd, Activity           activity) {
    this.arrayListAd = arrayListAd;
    this.activity = activity;
    dbfav = new DBFavourite(activity);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayListAd.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arrayListAd.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    TextView txtID;
    TextView txtName;
    ImageView imvFavourite;
    boolean isSelected;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customized_listview, null);  /* layout file for listview row items */
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtID = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_tv_textId); /* textview id  */
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_lv_names); /* texview for names */
        holder.imvFavourite = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_imv_favourite); /* imageview for favorite icons */
        holder.isSelected = false;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtID.setText(String.valueOf(arrayListAd.get(position).getNameId())); /* model class functions */
    holder.txtName.setText(arrayListAd.get(position).getName());  /* model class functions */

    if (arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() > 0) {
        holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fav_filled);
        holder.imvFavourite.setTag("Dark=" + holder.txtID.getText());

    } else if (arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() == 0) {
        holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fav_not_filled);
        holder.imvFavourite.setTag("Light=" + holder.txtID.getText());

    }
    if (holder.isSelected){
        // set the imvFavourite
    }else{
        // un set the imvFavourite. This is important!
    }

    holder.imvFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tagName = holder.imvFavourite.getTag().toString();
            String str[] = tagName.split("=");

            // Setting the isSelected field here
            holder.isSelected = true
            tagName = str[0];
            String strID = str[1];

            if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("Light")) {
                holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fav_filled);
                holder.imvFavourite.setTag("Dark=" + strID);
                dbfav.insertDataInFavourite(strID);  /* function inserts records in database */

            } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("Dark")) {
                holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fav_not_filled);
                holder.imvFavourite.setTag("Light=" + strID);
                dbfav.deleteByID(strID);            /* function that delete record from database */

            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: working but not as it should it also favorites the icons of outside's screen's fav icon ex. in my screen 10 records visible when i click 1st record (if second) and scroll than 11th record (than 12th) also favorited and this continues

Comment: @Dhaval: Is it possible `arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId()` to be less than zero?

Comment: ADDED some code but still not working scrolling problem solved but when press back and come back to icons changed @Shubham

Comment: @Dhaval that is because your isSelected field is lost when your Fragment is killed, if you need the selection when you come back to the screen you have to store it somewhere. It could either be activity level array or the database. I would say activity level array would be better option, as you don't need the selection to persist when the application is killed.

Comment: But when i use this adapter for fragments (In tabs) problem arises again @Shubham what i do?

Comment: When you are using fragments in tabs, when you swipe back to a fragment is the fragment instance killed and instantiated again or the fragment instance is retained. If it is retained then the problem should not occur.@Dhaval

Answer (score 0):

Use below given adapter class replace with your adapter class. 
First thing ViewHolder class is not static second thing never make or use final variable or class into getView() method. please refer this code. for more information refer this link.
[androidsimplifycodes.blogspot.in](http://androidsimplifycodes.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2017-03-15T22:40:00-07:00&max-results=1)

```
package com.androidsimplifycodes.example.ListView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidsimplifycodes.example.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList list;

    // passing the objects array list
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        // this condition only first time true because when adapter call that 
        // time your View is null so fist we bind xml file then after using ViewHolder 
        // bind views.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // bind your list_item.xml here 
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // if you not set holder into View then each and every time fist bind xml
            // then after make ViewHolder calls
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvText.setText(list.get(i).getText());

        return convertView;
    }

    // this class use for the memory utilization for example one time your 
    // xml view bind with java using findViewById then stored into ViewHolder
    // using setTag method. Here question arise but why required this procedure
    // because at run time each and every time not bind your xml view with adapter
    // it will be provide memory utilization and scrolling speed to the View.
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvText;

        ViewHolder(View rootView) {
            initView(rootView);
        }

        private void initView(View rootView) {
            tvText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved Problem while scrolling listview favorite icon changed

```
    public class AdapterFind extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<BeanFindName> arrayListAd; /* arraylist with model class */
        Activity activity;
        DBFavourite dbfav;                   /* database class */

        private boolean[] favorites;           `ADDED`


        public AdapterFind(ArrayList<BeanFindName> arrayListAd, Activity           activity) {
            this.arrayListAd = arrayListAd;
            this.activity = activity;
            dbfav = new DBFavourite(activity);

            favorites = new boolean[this.arrayListAd.size()];    `ADDED`

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayListAd.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return arrayListAd.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {

            TextView txtID;
            TextView txtName;
            ImageView imvFavourite;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customized_listview, null);  /* layout file for listview row items */
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtID = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_tv_textId); /* textview id  */
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_lv_names); /* texview for names */
                holder.imvFavourite = (ImageView) convertView
                       .findViewById(R.id.customized_listview_imv_favourite); /* imageview for favorite icons */

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtID.setText(String.valueOf(arrayListAd.get(position).getNameId())); /* model class functions */
            holder.txtName.setText(arrayListAd.get(position).getName());  /* model class functions */

            if (arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() > 0 || favorites[position]) {
                holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.customized_listview_iv_favourites_boy_filled);

            } else if (arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() == 0 || !favorites[position]) {
                holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.customized_listview_iv_favourites_boy_not_filled);
            }

            holder.imvFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

`ADDED`

      if (favorites[position] || arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() > 0) {  /* check for scrolling and database also to change favorite icon */
                        holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.customized_listview_iv_favourites_boy_not_filled);
                        dbfav.deleteByID(holder.txtID.getText().toString()); /* delete records from database*/
                        favorites[position] = false;
                    } else if (arrayListAd.get(position).getFinfavId() == 0 || !favorites[position]) {                          holder.imvFavourite.setImageResource(R.mipmap.customized_listview_iv_favourites_boy_filled);
         dbfav.insertDataInFavourite(holder.txtID.getText().toString()); /*inserts records to database */
                        favorites[position] = true; 
                    }
                 }               
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```